# Reparent X11 window on a JFrame or a JPanel?

Tags: java, jframe, jpanel, x11, reparenting

In order to embed a C/C++ X11 application into another Java application, is it possible to reparent the X11 top level widget in:

- a JFrame or a JWindow (catching the X11 window ids of their X11 peers using package sun.awt.x11)?
- or a JPanel?

I would prefer reparent with a JPanel but I'm not sure it's possible.

Comment: Hello, I don't understand why I get a -1 vote. What is the problem with my question?

Comment: First question: can you embed the C++ application in the JVM using JNI, or do they have to remain as separate applications? It's easier to do this if you have the apps linked together.

Comment: Second question: is OpenGL involved?

Comment: Never tried this, but maybe this method will help: http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/jdk/jdk-6u23/sun/awt/X11/XPanelPeer.html#xembed(long)

Comment: First question: no they have to remain as separate applications. Second question: no OpenGL involved.

Answer (score 2):

I searched and found:

A recursive function that will search (starting from the root window) for a window with the desired name

```
Window windowWithName(Display *dpy, Window top, char *name)
{
        Window *children, dummy;
        unsigned int nchildren;
        unsigned int i;
        Window w = 0;
        char *window_name;

        if (XFetchName(dpy, top, &window_name) && !strcmp(window_name, name))
                return (top);

        if (!XQueryTree(dpy, top, &dummy, &dummy, &children, &nchildren))
                return (0);

        for (i = 0; i < nchildren; i++)
        {
                w = windowWithName(dpy, children[i], name);
                if (w)
                        break;
        }
        if (children)
                XFree((char *) children);
        return (w);
}
```

You can always open a `java.net.Socket` to **port 6000** or so and speak `X11` yourself.
[code that might help](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/X11Forwarding.java)

[reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1529526/to-create-x-windowx11-in-java-swing-and-to-get-its-id), hope this help
**NOTE:** package `sun.awt.x11` is **no more** in `jdk7`

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to try your solution. Keep inform.